# React TestUtils doesn't work with decorators or how to mock higher order functions using rewire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs

I have a higher order component:

```
import React from 'react';

function withMUI(ComposedComponent) {
  return class withMUI {
    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props}/>;
    }
  };
}
```

and a component:

```
@withMUI
class PlayerProfile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name, avatar } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="player-profile">
        <div className='profile-name'>{name}</div>
        <div>
          <Avatar src={avatar}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and a (passing) test using `React.findDOMNode`

```
describe('PlayerProfile', () => {
  // profile is type of `withMUI`
  let profile = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<OkeyPlayerProfile/>);

  it('should work', () => {
    let elem = React.findDOMNode(profile);

    // logs successfully
    console.log(elem.querySelectorAll('.player-profile'));
  });

  // ...
});
```

and another (failing) test using `TestUtils`:

```
   // ...
   it('should also work', () => {
     let elem = TestUtils.findComponentWithTag(profile, 'div');
     // throws can't find a match
     console.log(elem);
   });
```

If I remove the @withMUI decorator it works as expected. So why does a decorator effect `TestUtils.findComponentWithTag` and how can I make this work?

How can I mock `withMUI` function? using [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire). or rewire?

Comment: When I've used `findComponentWithTag`, I recall that it returns all matches regardless of depth. If this is the same for you, I would expect 3 matches for `div`, and an error response. If you use `scryComponentsWithTag`, it will return an array with all matches. Does the array have 0 length, or 3?

Comment: It's 0 @JeffFairley but it is 3 if I don't use `withMUI`

Comment: K. Thanks. Just had to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'babel-plugin-remove-decorators' plugin

Install the plugin first, then create a file with the following content, let us call it 'babelTestingHook.js'

```
require('babel/register')({
 'stage': 2,
 'optional': [
  'es7.classProperties',
  'es7.decorators',
  // or Whatever configs you have
  .....
],
'plugins': ['babel-plugin-remove-decorators:before']
});
```

and running your tests like below will ignore the decorators and you will be able to test the components normally

```
mocha ./tests/**/*.spec.js --require ./babelTestingHook.js --recursive
```